# Summon a chest with enchanted items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Everytime I try to use a command to do an enchanted item it never works and there's just a 0 next to the item. I tried to spawn a diamond sword with sharpness in a chest but instead in the chest there was a normal diamond sword with a 0 next to it. Is it possible to put an enchanted weapon/item in a chest?

Comment: (the syntax for enchanted items is the exact same whether done via /give or in a chest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/setblock ~1 ~ ~ chest 0 replace {Items:[{id:"diamond_sword",Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:16,lvl:1}]},Slot:13}]}
```

Try that by using a command block `/give @p command_block 1`

That will summon a chest 1 block to the left of the command block filled with a sharpness 1 diamond sword :)

Comment: I need it in a chest, this just gives it directly to you.

Comment: ah yes, sorry let me edit that a sec.

Comment: also, I got this error when I did it:    [21:06:02] '{ench:[{id:16,lvl:1}]}' is not a valid number

Comment: what version of minecraft and are you using a command block?

Comment: I have the latest version of minecraft and I'm playing multiplayer (if that makes a difference)

Comment: 1.8.7? It should work then, you using a command block?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25551/discussion-between-skye-and-chickenator).

Comment: I copied and pasted it and this time for some reason I got [21:09:52] Unknown command. Try /help for a list of commands