# Summoning chest with specific items using name and lore

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

**I want to summon a chest** with one custom item inside that has a custom name and lore tag. I have not found any posts about this specific situation.

The item I want to have inside the chest is a tripwire hook named "Small Key" with the lore tag "This key may only be used at your current location." [As a give command]:

```
/give @a Minecraft:tripwire_hook{display:{Name:"\"Small Key\"",Lore:["\"This key may only be used at your current location.\""]}} 1
```

**I have already tried** using mcstacker.net but there is no available command for chests, only minecarts with chests. I tried to change `chest_minecart` to only chest, but this does not work in-game.
The command given from mcstacker.net is:

```
/summon chest_minecart ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[10.0,49.0,89.0],Items:[{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Small Key"}',Lore:['{"text":"This key may only be used at your current location."}']}}}]}
```

I have also looked in other threads and forums for answers but I have not found anything that helps.
Examples:

- [Refilling a chest with "special" item](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253225/refilling-a-chest-with-special-item/253235#253235)
- [Summon a chest with enchanted items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226637/summon-a-chest-with-enchanted-items)
- [Parsing failed error when spawning a chest preloaded with items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235602/parsing-failed-error-when-spawning-a-chest-preloaded-with-items)

**Here on** there is also another question asked, why does the following command work:

```
/summon chest_minecart ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[10.0,49.0,89.0],Items:[{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Small Key"}',Lore:['{"text":"This key may only be used at your current location."}']}}}]}
```

while this command does not?

```
/summon chest ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[10.0,49.0,89.0],Items:[{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Small Key"}',Lore:['{"text":"This key may only be used at your current location."}']}}}]}
```

*Note: `chest_minecart` can be replaced with all other blocks, even entities. But **not** `chest`.*

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct command:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~1 chest{Items:[{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Small Key"}',Lore:['{"text":"This key may only be used at your current location."}']}}}]} replace
```

The reason as to why `chest_minecart` can't be replaced with `chest` is that /summon is specific for entities and /setblock for blocks.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Thanks!

Comment: Idly wondering, what got you into thinking that a chest was an entity? It doesn't move like a chest minecart, and has a block outline when you hover over it. MCStacker also showed you that a chest was not an entity because its summon generator does not have `chest` in the list.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Well, to be honest, I feel rather stupid after finding out what the issue was. It was a while ago I was playing around with commands and commandblocks. If we go back to the time when I knew what I was doing, the block/entity ID:s where still integers and not strings, so it was a while ago.